# syntax issues regarding JOIN and WITH in SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, with-statement

I am new at T-SQL so please bear with me.

I am attempting to follow the following instructions:

Do the following

```
Join Indivs16000 to Cmtes16 on Indivs16000.CmteID = Cmtes16.CmteID 
with  Indivs16000.RecipCode not like P*
```

If you want to include individual contributions to leadership PACs, do NOT exclude based on Recipcode. Instead, limit to where Indivs.Party is not null and Indivs.Party<>”” (does not equal blank.)

I want to include individual contributions to leadership PACS. In an attempt to follow these instructions I wrote the following query:

```
JOIN Indivs16000 to Cmtes16
ON Indivs16000.CmteID = Cmtes16.CmteID
WITH Indivs16000.Party NOT NULL
AND Indivs16000.Party<>
```

Upon execution I hit the following errors:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Join'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
```

What is going wrong? I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (Management Studio).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sean Lange pointed out, `i.Party<>''` or `i.Party > ''` eliminate the need to check if `i.Party` is `null`.

You can choose which columns you want to return, and from which table they should come from, in your `select`.

Using aliases for your table names make things more readable, and save you from wasting some of your [finite number of keystrokes](http://keysleft.com/).

```
select 
    i.*
  , c.col1
  , c.col2
from Indivs16000 as i
  inner join Cmtes16 as c
    on i.CmteID = c.CmteID
where i.Party<>''
  --and i.Party is not null /* not needed with i.Party <>'' */
```

Comment: Your solution worked. It appears that both the Indivs table and the Cmtes table shared a column called Cycle (the value for cycle is always the same). This caused my query to give me two cycle columns. This is pretty irritating. Do you suppose I can avoid this by replacing the asterisk with the table.column(s) that I want in the new table so I can specify that I want only one cycle column?

Comment: You could simplify the where statement to Indivs16000.Party > ''. This will eliminate null and empty string at the same time.

Comment: @SeanLange I thought about that, but it looked like this was homework so I didn't want to change his answer, just correct his form. Good point though!

Comment: @anang Yes, you can just select the columns instead of the asterisk

Comment: @SeanLange @SqlZim It is a personal project. Eliminating null and empty at the same time could be very valuable to me. So basically it would look like this `WHERE Indivs16000.Party >"` if I wanted to do that?

Comment: Correct. You might also consider using aliases for your tables in your query. It will make it more legible and less typing. :)

Comment: @anang `Indivs16000.Party<>''` or `Indivs16000.Party > ''` would work

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
Indivs16000 as A
INNER JOIN 
Cmtes16 as B
ON A.CmteID = B.CmteID
WHERE AND A.Party != '' and A.Party is not null
```

Comment: I would avoid the "!=". It is not ANSI-SQL. Use "<>" instead

Comment: @asemprini87 right, I get used to use that in sql server xD, even ISNULL, etc

Comment: @asemprini87 They're equivalent in Sql Server, no need to get ANSI about it ^.^